# SQL Count column remaining at 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to display a running total of Invoice_Amount. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT cust_name, COUNT(*) as Invoice_Amount, Invoice.invoice_date
FROM Customer, Invoice
WHERE Customer.customer_id = Invoice.customer_id
GROUP BY Invoice.customer_id, Customer.cust_name,invoice_date;
```

and here is the current output:

```
cust_name                   Invoice_Amount        invoice_date
Company A                   1                     2000-10-12 00:00:00.000
Company B                   1                     2000-09-22 00:00:00.000
Company C                   1                     2000-05-26 00:00:00.000
Company D                   1                     2000-08-15 00:00:00.000
Company E                   1                     2000-11-15 00:00:00.000
Company E                   1                     2000-05-02 00:00:00.000
```

Where I  would like the Invoice_Amount in both cases to read 2 like so:

```
cust_name                   Invoice_Amount        invoice_date
Company A                   1                     2000-10-12 00:00:00.000
Company B                   1                     2000-09-22 00:00:00.000
Company C                   1                     2000-05-26 00:00:00.000
Company D                   1                     2000-08-15 00:00:00.000
Company E                   2                     2000-11-15 00:00:00.000
Company E                   2                     2000-05-02 00:00:00.000
```

This is so I can eventually do something along the lines of:

```
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

How would I go about getting to this result

Comment: 1) Its not best practice to use comma joins as you are doing. I suggest changing them to proper joins. 2) Count gives you the number of rows aggregated by the `group by` clause. But you aren't aggregating, and therefore don't need a `group by` clause. What you want is a window function.

Comment: So you ultimately want all invoices (including details) for customers that have multiple orders?

Comment: @shawnt00 Yes but also showing the invoice_date, so not simply just grouping by cust_name and having(count(*))>1

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by details.

Comment: @shawnt00 Then yes

Comment: Also I recommend short, meaningful aliases i.e. `I` for `Invoice` - it makes your code much easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a `GROUP BY` or a `HAVING` because you're not actually grouping by anything in the final result.

```
;;;/* CTE with leading semi-colons for safety */;;;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT c.cust_name, i.invoice_date, 
    COUNT(i.invoice_date) OVER (PARTITION BY i.customer_id)
       AS Invoice_Count
  FROM dbo.Customer AS c
    INNER JOIN dbo.Invoice AS i
    ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id
)
SELECT cust_name, Invoice_Count, invoice_date
FROM src
  -- WHERE Invoice_Count > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, can I ask what the dbo is for

Comment: @SecretFerret https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix

Answer (score 0):

Well, as from your data, the combinations of `invoice_date` and `cust_name` seem to be unique - as COUNT(*) always returns 1.

You now seem to need the count value that you call `invoice_amount` to tally up for the same `cust_name`. 'Chopsticks' is occurring twice in your report, and, for 'Chopsticks', you need the value 2. But, still, you want to keep both rows.

Functions that sort-of aggregate data, but still return the same number of rows as the input, are not GROUP BY or aggregate functions, they are window functions, or OLAP/Analytic functions.

So, start from your grouping query, but then select from it, applying an OLAP function , and select from that outer query in turn, filtering for the OLAP function's result:

```
WITH
grp AS (
  SELECT 
    cust_name
  , count(*) AS invoice_amount
  , invoice.invoice_date
  FROM customer
  JOIN invoice ON customer.customer_id = invoice.customer_id
  GROUP BY  
    invoice.customer_id
  , customer.cust_name
  , invoice_date;
)
,
olap AS (
  SELECT
    cust_name
  , SUM(invoice_amount) OVER(PARTITION BY cust_name) AS invoice_amount
  , invoice_date
  FROM grp 
)
SELECT
  *
FROM olap
WHERE invoice_amount > 1;
```

Comment: Seems like serious overkill?

Comment: @marcothesane Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, the following is the error: "customer_id" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.

Comment: I forgot that SQL Server does not support the ANSI standard USING() join predicate. I changed it to an ON clause now, and it should work.

Comment: @DaleK - I just take it as a given that the input needs grouping - we don't know the original input. So I don't know if I can combine all into an OLAP function or if grouping is required before, so I stay on the safe side. And I don't remember if SQL Server supports the QUALIFY filter on OLAP functions.